# Spreadsheet formula for order subtotal

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

[image]I am trying to figure out a basic way to have a spreadsheet with a few columns, A: Account name, B: Product code, C: Quantity.  Then elsewhere, perhaps on another worksheet, I would like to display a total area with all products and respective quantities for each listed.

** One other thing I would like to add to that, is the ability to have a fourth column, D: Driver, which I could then list a delivery driver/route, so that I could just display the sub totals just for a specific driver.

I have been trying this unsuccessfully in Google Sheets, but I do have the most recent MS Office Excel as well, if there is some other feature that might make this an easier endeavor.  Hopefully this makes sense, and thanks for any suggestions!!

Comment: Do you know about pivot tables?

Comment: A little bit.... though I just wanted something very quick to use for someone inputting the orders coming in... so they could just enter things quickly and have totals compiled on the fly

Comment: Basically so they didn't have to enter a customer name over and over or keep selecting them just for each product... just select them once, and have a line following for each product ordered

Answer (score 0):

Wonder is Pivot is the item that what your looking for? 
[image]

EDITTED :
Table at sheet 1:
[image: sheet 1 table]

Editted base on question change:

Is this what you need?
[image]

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Possibly??  But I just want something very simple that someone can enter the account/client name just once, and then somehow go through and add additional rows... is there a way to do that?  What if we have, say 20 different products?  It seems like it starts to get pretty long at that point and hard to navigate on the screen

Comment: You can uncheck the product code / remove the product code from the columns at PivotTable Field if you would like to see sum of quantity only. You can add in the rows in the table at sheet 1 (a table is not a simply cell in the worksheet but it is created through insert > table) and refresh the pivot to get the data you need. I form this pivot by using table.

Comment: @bonCodigo , I would like to add it as comment but it just fulfill the criteria that the user looking for, so I added it as answer. Furthermore, I am lack of the reputation point to add a comment. That's my hardship

Comment: I think that gets me pretty close... yes...  Any other tips or templates are appreciated

Comment: As you mention it "pretty close" , could i know is there still got anything you want to do to the pivot?